# Unable to parse a json field class using Jackson jar

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json response :

```
"site":[  
               {  
                  "href":"https:www.abc.com",
                  "class":"child"
               }
]
```

I am trying to parse the response using the jackson jars in Java.
I cant create a field class(as its a keyword) in my POJO to map this field.
I tried class_ and _class but that returns org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "class" as it searches for the field class in my POJO Site.java
How can such scenarios be handled?

Comment: I resolved this with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property name in your POJO cannot be name "class", but you can specify to Jackson to use the property name "class" with the annotation.

```
@JsonProperty("class")
private String clazz;
```